# Expand Query Azure Mobile Services to children of children

Tags: api, azure-mobile-services, navigation-properties

I've been able to use an Expand attribute in my C# API for Azure Mobile Services to expand the child object and it works great.

However, that child object also has a child object, which I want to be able to use when getting the top level item.

That is, I'm Querying the table Items, which has a property "SubCategory", but that subcategory object also has a property "ParentCategory".

I want to be able to populate the objects two levels down, but it seems the $expand query will only work on the direct properties of the table being queried.

Is there a way to get what I want? Ultimately what I'm wanting to do is when I show the list of all the Items, show both the subcategory and parent category in a table. Right now, I can only see the subcategory, as the parent property of that subcategory is null.

I thought perhaps adding the ParentCategoryId and ParentCategory objects to the DataObject definitions, but this seems incorrect, since I would have to maintain that integrity manually, instead of letting it link via the subcategory property...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to do a recursive query, which is handled with Common Table Expressions.  The way I would do it is to create a View within SQL that has the ParentCategory and SubCategory for every item.  Then my search can target ParentCategory or SubCategory easily.

You can check out an article on hierarchical queries here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Although the technique is documented for Oracle DB, you can also read how SQL Server (and SQL Azure) handles this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Then you would write your table controller to access the View.

Comment: ah okay this sounds promising, but if I understand you correctly you are saying that for this view I'm trying to construct I cannot do it with the azure mobile services client, and have to build a custom api call to get the results I need. would that be a correct assumption?

Comment: No, you can use the regular Table Controller. In your db context, you should connect to the view rather than the table. Here's an article that walks through it: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/02/leverage-views-in-entity-framework.aspx